# Tensorflow's computation time gradually slowing down in very simple "for loop"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a very strange problem on tensorflow.  I simplified my question to the following version：

I just write a simple Matrix multiplication in tensorflow language, then I put this Matrix multiplication in a "for loop"(Of course you can put other complicated functions in the for loop, the conclusion is same).

I set 10000 iterations times， and print the time consuming in each loop, then I can observe that the consumption of time is gradually increasing.（I wish the time for each loop should be same，but it didn't.)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import datetime  

graph=tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():  
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        a=np.arange(10).reshape(1,-1)
        b=np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
        A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1,10])
        B = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10,10])


        sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

        for step in range(10000):
            starttime = datetime.datetime.now()  

            RESULT = tf.matmul(A,B)
            RESULT=sess.run(RESULT,feed_dict={A: a, B: b})

            endtime = datetime.datetime.now()  
            print(endtime-starttime)
```

at the begining, the program print the following result:

```
0:00:00.003058
0:00:00.003216
0:00:00.003195
0:00:00.003213
0:00:00.003653
0:00:00.003599
0:00:00.003297
0:00:00.003172
0:00:00.003235
0:00:00.004374
0:00:00.003442
0:00:00.003387
0:00:00.003290
```

after few seconds, I got this:

```
0:00:00.011470
0:00:00.013232
0:00:00.013088
0:00:00.015906
0:00:00.012659
0:00:00.012914
0:00:00.012562
0:00:00.011941
0:00:00.013575
0:00:00.012251
0:00:00.013759
0:00:00.012534
0:00:00.011859

...

0:00:00.031062
0:00:00.031676
0:00:00.031388
0:00:00.031349
0:00:00.032476
0:00:00.031337
0:00:00.031147
0:00:00.031121
0:00:00.030795
0:00:00.031143
0:00:00.031277
0:00:00.031015
0:00:00.034139
0:00:00.032749
```

It means the calculation is slowing down. Can anyone tell me why?  thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a new operation every time you go through your loop. (tf.matmul)

As such, your tensorflow graph is growing out of control.

In tensorflow you create your operations once (ex : tf.matmul(A,B)), and then you execute this operation multiple times using sess.run (ex : sess.run(RESULT, feed_dict={A: ai, B: bi}.

Creating an operation is like writing a function or creating a processing unit, you only need to create it once and then you can use it with many inputs.

Comment: thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!! ，besides，You answered very quickly！！！！！！！！！！！！！，you are correct！！！！！！！！！

Answer (score 5):

Arnaud is correct. To add on to his answer, what you should be doing is the following:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import datetime  

graph=tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():  
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        a = np.arange(10).reshape(1,-1)
        b = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
        A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1,10])
        B = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10,10])
        C = tf.matmul(A,B) #changed

        sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

        for step in range(10000):
            starttime = datetime.datetime.now()  

            RESULT = sess.run(C,feed_dict={A: a, B: b}) #changed

            endtime = datetime.datetime.now()  
            print(endtime-starttime)
```

In this way, you are creating operation `tf.matmul` only once.